# Problema al redireccionar vista desde otro controlador

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

*Esta es mi función que envía, he tomado de ejemplos que he visto en este foro*

```
function enviarDatos() {
        var params = {
            valor1 : $("#usuario").val(),
            valor2 : $("#clave").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: "post",
            data: params,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    //Refresh
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

*Así lo recibo en el controlador
el debug pasa por el RedirectToAction y finaliza el metodo, pero no redirecciona
No he encontrado ayuda con respecto a este tema en el cual no tengo experiencia*

```
public ActionResult Index(string usuario, string pass)
    {
        try
        {                
            usuario = Request.Form.Get("valor1");
            pass = Request.Form.Get("valor2");
            bool valida = true;
           //Usuario usu = new Usuario();
           //valida = usu.ReadAll(usuario, pass); 

            if (valida)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Inicio", "Inicio");
            }
```

Comment: Saludos bro, bienvenido a SOes, revisa este workshop que hice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY justo para personas que andan iniciando con ASP.Net MVC

Comment: @BastianSalasar No va a redireccionar ya que la vista se carga en el `ajax`, por lo tanto `window.location.reload();` recargara la vista en la que estas, te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a lo que ha compartido @fredyfx, si quieres leer puedes ver esta web https://si.ua.es/es/documentacion/asp-net-mvc-3/1-dia/modelo-vista-controlador-mvc.html

Comment: Por cierto, este documento te será de utilidad cuando trabajes las vistas con Razor: https://www.slideshare.net/fredyfx/tutorial-ms-web-matrixv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se recarga la nueva pagina que estas solicitando por el simple hecho de que no estas haciendo un redireccionamiento.

**AJAX** sirve para evitar refrescar la pagina y cargar contenido a la pagina actual.

AHora lo que necesitas es hacer un `submit` del formulario en **ASP .NET MVC** puedes hacer lo siguiente

**Vista index:** (tu vista donde tienes el ajax).

```
<body>
  <!--form action="@Url.Action("Vista","Controlador")" method="post"-->
  <form action="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
  </form>
</body>
<!-- He quitado el ajax ya que no voy a recargar la vista en esta url -->
```

**Controlador Home**

```
//get
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
[HttpPost]//se recibe el post con la informacion del logeo
public ActionResult Index(ModeloLogin model)
{
  //validando la informacion
  if (valida)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Inicio", "Inicio");
    //si la informacion es valida redireccionamos a la nueva vista
  }
  return View();//volvemos a la vista index
}
```

**ModeloLogin** //se requiere para parsear la informacion que ingreso en los input.

```
public class ModeloLogin
{
  //variables para cargar los datos enviados por el usuario
  public String UserName { get; set; }
  public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> 1. Para que entiendas un poco mas el concepto de **MVC** en **ASP .NET
>      MVC** revisa
>      https://si.ua.es/es/documentacion/asp-net-mvc-3/1-dia/modelo-vista-controlador-mvc.html
> 2. O si prefieres algo mas visual el workshop del buen fredyfx https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: gracias hermano por la consideración del material :D

Answer (score 1):

Corrigiendo las funciones presentadas en el problema, pude resolver el problema, primero el método que envía al server:

```
    function enviarDatos() {
            var params = {
                valor1 : $("#usuario").val(),
                valor2 : $("#clave").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                 content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: params,
                 success: function (respuesta) {
                       if (respuesta.model == '1') {
                          location.href = "Home/Inicio/";
                      } else if (respuesta.model == '2'){
                        Alert.render('El usuario ingresado no está registrado');
                      } else if (respuesta.model == '3'){
                        Alert.render('La clave ingresada es incorrecta');
                      } else {
                         Alert.render('Error: Ocurrió un problema en el método "Validar Usuario"');
                      }
                },
                  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     Alert.render('Error: No se pudo cargar método "Validar Usuario"');
                  }
               });
}
```

Luego modificar el método en el server

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            //obtiene valores de usuaio y clave del FormCollection
            string usuario = collection["Usuario"].ToString();
            string pass = collection["Clave"].ToString();
            UsuarioDAL dal = new UsuarioDAL();
            //solicita validacion del usuario
            int valida = dal.ValidarUsuario(usuario, pass);
            int model = 0;
            if (valida == 1)
            {
                model = 1;//usuario y clave correctos                    
            }
            else if (valida == 3)
            {
                model = 2;//El usuario ingresado no está registrado
            }
            else if (valida == 2)
            {
                model = 3;//La clave ingresada es incorrecta
            }

            //valida que el metodo de validacion no venga como un "catch"
            var result = new { Success = true, Message = "Succes Message", model };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            var result = new { Success = false, Message = "Error Message" };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }//fin IniciarSesion()
```

Al utilizar las respuestas con AJAX, se puede tener un mejor control del estado de la consulta